# relative URL path question

Tags: asp.net, html

Why does this work in design mode but not when I run it:

```
<tr style="background-image: url('~/images/button.gif');">
```

...and this works in both design and run time mode?

```
<tr style="background-image: url('images/button.gif');">
```

The images folder is one folder below the aspx page which contains this HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At run time, the style value gets to the browser with the tilde, and the client does not know anything about it. You should do something like this:

```
<tr style="background-image: url(<%= ResolveUrl ('~/images/button.gif') %>">
```

Answer (score 1):

The relative path is only known on the server.  Putting it in the source (either HTML or, in this case, CSS), tells the client's browser to make a separate request for that file at the specified url.  The '~' won't mean anything to the client's computer, so the request won't be made to the correct url.